# Как сделать, чтобы при переходе по определенной ссылке на страницу появлялись дополнительные css свойства

Tags: javascript, css

Вообщем у меня есть ссылка на одной странице и раскрывающийся знаком + список на другом. Мне необходимо, чтобы при переходе по этой ссылке страница открылась уже с раскрытым списком. Как это можно реализовать? Создавать дополнительную страницу не вариант как минимум потому, что ссылок таких будет 5 и 5 разных списков на одной странице. Список открывается путем изменения свойства display с none на block.

Comment: передавать гет параметр....анализировать URL и в зависимости от того, что там нужно - добавлять стили

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка должна быть с дополнительным параметром. Например нам нужно открыть листы 1 и 3:

```
https://site.com?listOpen=1&listOpen=3
```

Читаем наши параметры `URL`, они записаны в `window.location.search`.

```js
const listsToOpen = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).getAll('listOpen'); // получаем массив строк ['1', '3'];
for (let list of listsToOpen) {
 document.querySelector(`[data-list="${list}"]`).style.display = 'block'; // Я не знаю как вы захотите искать эти листы в документе, если так же, то не забудьте добавить атрибут data-list="<номер листа>" к элементам листов
}
```

- Подробенее про [интерфейс Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location).
- Про конструкцию [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

#### UPD

Чтобы было покомпактнее, можно использовать 1 параметр такого вида:

```
https://site.com?listOpen=13
```

Затем обработать его таким образом:

```js
const listsToOpen = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('listOpen'); // получаем строку '13';
for (let list of listsToOpen) {
 document.querySelector(`[data-list="${list}"]`).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Но это будет работать только если этих листов будет <= 10(от 0 до 9), т.к, например, `data-list="23"` будет восприниматься как листы с `data-list="2"` и `data-list="3"`. Там уже нужен будет алгоритм посложнее.

Comment: "только если этих листов будет <= 10" - а можно просто написать listOpen=1,3

Comment: @Kain, в общем-то да. Вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот дедовский метод для поддержки старых браузеров:

```js
var params = location.search.slice(1).split('&')
for(let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    let a = params[i].split('=')
    if(a[0] === 'listOpen') {
      document.querySelector('[data-list="'+ a[1] +'"]').style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

Пример ссылки:

```
https://example.com/page?listOpen=1&listOpen=2&listOpen=34
```