# Помогите с освоением get параметров пожалуйста!

Tags: javascript, url, get

Задача следующая:
при переходе по ссылке такого вида *http://localhost:3000/html/legal-aid.html#desc__criminal?listOpen=1* хочу задавать значение для get параметра. Всего значений у параметра будет 5. В зависимости от значения параметра на открывшейся странице определенному блоку (5 блоков с разными id и class) должно присваиваться значение display: block. При этом если перехожу на страницу без get параметра, то ни у одного блока свойства не должны меняться. Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Никак не могу разобраться, постоянно не работает почему-то. А очень необходимо увидеть как работает и понять)) Для примера названия двух блоков у которых должно свойство display меняться: crim-block (class), arb-block (class). id такие же.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы при переходе по определенной ссылке на страницу появлялись дополнительные css свойства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1424611/405855)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.